# How do you make Spring Hateaos return HAL/XML?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hateoas, spring-hateoas

Using a spring-mvc controller method annotated with `produces = {"application/hal+json"}` spring-hateoas will return HAL/JSON.

I require the equivalent for XML. I have tried putting `"application/hal+xml"` in the `produces` annotation but that doesn't do the trick. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

From looking at the hateoas code, I believe that HAL/XML is not currently supported:

```
public static List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getDefaultMessageConverters(List<MediaType> mediaTypes) {

    Assert.notNull(mediaTypes, "Media types must not be null!");

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    if (mediaTypes.contains(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON)) {
        converters.add(getHalConverter());
    }

    return converters;
}
```